# How do I log swagger / connexion request body?

Tags: python-logging, connexion

I'm using connexion and Swagger to create an API in Python. I'd like to log all of the incoming calls to a file so I can see what's being requested. I've been able to log the path of the calls I've received but I can't figure out how to log the body.

Here's where I've configured my logging:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',                            filename='golden_record.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

When I look into the log, I see the path, as in the following for a POST call...

> 2019-03-23 12:47:16,182 - werkzeug - INFO - 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Mar/2019
>   12:47:16] "POST /golden_record/account HTTP/1.1" 400 -

but I don't see the body of the call (i.e. the data I've sent). Is there a way to automatically record this for every call that comes in? Doing so would help debug calls that aren't functioning as desired. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a Flask before_request.
Connexion instance stores the Flask instance as the `app` attribute, so you can access using `app.app`.

Add the code and you will log the body:

```
@app.app.before_request
 def log_request_info():
    print('Body: %s', request.get_data())
```

Change the `print` method to your logger:

```
@app.app.before_request
 def log_request_info():
    logger.info('Body: %s', request.get_data())
```

The `request` import is :

`from flask import request`

And the `app`  is your Connexion instance:

`app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir="./swagger/")`

I created a Gist with the code.
https://gist.github.com/kevinmmartins/f832c21215bb51cea73b8fdd28f6d88d